# vlsam rviz error

Tags: ros, vslam-system, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The command "rosrun rviz rviz -d --sync simple_vslam.vcg" worked very well before I upgrade my Ubuntu system. Now it just shows the errors:

[ INFO] [1314796403.849753950]: Loading general config from [/home/liu/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1314796403.850233372]: Loading display config from [/home/liu/.rviz/display_config]
The program 'rviz' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
(Details: serial 29 error_code 3 request_code 138 minor_code 4)
(Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)

Anyone has the same problem? My system right now is Ubuntu natty 11.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11072/vlsam-rviz-error/) by [GuoliangLiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1015/guoliangliu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2011-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

vslam is unsupported experimental research code. It is not actively being supported, but patches are welcome.

However, this appears to be a problem with rviz rather than with vslam. Instead of loading the vcg, try adding the pose markers and points to rviz manually.

---

Originally posted by [Helen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1033/helen/) with karma: 261 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0